# Where does tag in `git diff tag` refer to? How does it find where tag points to?

Tags: git

Where does tag in `git diff tag` refer to?

I know that the tag is the tag of HEAD of the project(s) being compared.
However, if I'm using it like:

```
git diff tag1
```

and omit tag2, meaning that I'm in the workind directory of what tag2 would refer to. Then where does tag1 point to? Must I have acquired the project where tag1 refers to somehow? Or have it in my git or something (that I cannot refer to other people's repos)?

How does it find where tag points to?

Comment: Use `git rev-parse` to find out what commit any revision parameter (including tag names) refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ git diff tag1` will show the changes between the working tree and the index or in your case `tag1`.

You can refer to [Documentation.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: Okay so it assumes that the working directory is the same as that in git?

Comment: Yes you can compare with a remote branch $ git diff <localbranch_path> <remotebranch_path>  Example:  $ git diff tag1 origin/master

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you might have the wrong mental model for how `git diff` works, and/or for how tags and other Git *references* (or *refs*—a technical term here) work.

As [chepner said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425907/where-does-tag-in-git-diff-tag-refer-to-how-does-it-find-where-tag-points-to#comment95662241_54425907), you can use `git rev-parse` to find the Git hash ID for any parse-able revision specifier.  The syntax for revision specifiers is detailed in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

Git is a *distributed* version control system, and its design means that each Git repository is a complete, standalone collection of *all* commits.<sup>1</sup>  The "true name" of each commit is some big ugly hash ID, such as `0d0ac3826a3bbb9247e39e12623bbcfdd722f24c`.  You can use this ID at any time to tell Git: *look at this particular commit.*  These names are virtually useless to humans, though, so we add human-readable names.  These include *tag* names like `v1.1`—its full name is actually `refs/tags/v1.1`—but these tag names are merely names for the hash ID.

When you run `git diff`, in general, you select two commits—really, two *trees* (another Git technical term), but there's a one-to-one map from a commit hash ID or equivalent, to its tree—to compare.  Git extracts both trees and compares them, giving you an overall diff that typically also contains a file-at-a-time diff of paired-up files.

If you select *one* commit with `git diff`, the second tree it uses is whatever you have in your work-tree.  The work-tree contents are not a commit, at least not yet, but it's extremely useful to be able to compare a tree—such as the most recent commit's tree—against the work-tree's contents.

Annoyingly but very usefully, Git doesn't make new commits from the work-tree at all.  Instead, it makes them from a *third* tree, which Git calls the *index* (or sometimes the *staging area* or *cache*, depending on which part of Git is doing this calling).  So Git needs to be able to compare the index to the work-tree, or a commit to the index, and `git diff` can do these as well.

For the particular case of `git diff tag1`, Git will first turn `tag1` into a commit or tree hash ID using the equivalent of:

```
git rev-parse tag1^{tree}
```

The `^{tree}` bit is gitrevisions syntax for: *Whatever this is, I need the tree part of a commit, so if you can translate it into that, we're good.  I'll use the tree ID you provide to do my job.  If not, complain and die.*  Now that `git diff` has one tree ID and nothing else, it figures: *OK, you want me to compare the tree you named, to the contents of your work-tree.*  So that's what it compares.  It's up to you to make sure that the work-tree contents are what you care about (and of course that the name you supply identifies the correct starting tree for the compare).

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, that's really just *all commits in the repository*, but that's kind of tautological.  The idea here is that in the general case you always have all commits; if you're short a few, you use `git fetch` to have your Git call up some other Git and pick up any new commits that you lack, and now you're complete again.  If you add new commits to *your* repository, you have your Git deliver them to some other Git, by having them fetch from you, or using `git push` to shovel your commits at some other Git.

Git does support *shallow* repositories that deliberately omit some commits.  If you have a shallow repository, you do not have, and hence cannot use, any references to any commits that you don't have.  Any attempt to bring in such a reference automatically brings in its commit(s) as needed, so that you get both at the same time.  Thus, by definition, if you have a reference—such as a tag name like `v1.1`—you also have its commit.